# Attach Event Receiver to SharePoint Document Library using CSOM C#: 2010

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, csom

I have created an Event Receiver Assembly and installed in **`GAC`** as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg749858(v=office.14).aspx#Anchor_1). In that assembly I have override **`ItemAdded`** and **`ItemUpdated`** events.

The assembly has been successfully installed in **`GAC`**.

Now what I want is to attach that event receiver to my document library in SP2010 using CSOM C#.

I found the great article [Attach Event Receiver to SharePoint List using CSOM (Client Side Object Model)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/3428/attach-event-receiver-to-sharepoint-list-using-csom-client-side-object-model.aspx).

Code :

```
 using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{

    List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList");
    var eventReceivers = documentLibrary.EventReceivers;
    clientContext.Load(eventReceivers);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    EventReceiverType eventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
    string receiverAssembly = "EventHandlerName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8996123dfc8d0aa2";
    string receiverClass = "EventHandlerName.EventHandler";
    string receiverName = "Item Added Event";       //you can give any name  

    bool isEventReceiverAlreadyAssociated = false;
    foreach (var eventReceiver in eventReceivers)
    {
        if (eventReceiver.EventType == eventType
                && string.Compare(eventReceiver.ReceiverAssembly, receiverAssembly, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                && string.Compare(eventReceiver.ReceiverClass, receiverClass, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                && string.Compare(eventReceiver.ReceiverName, receiverName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
            )
        {
            isEventReceiverAlreadyAssociated = true;
        }
    }

    if (!isEventReceiverAlreadyAssociated)
    {
        EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation eventReceiver
            = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation
            {
                EventType = eventType,
                ReceiverAssembly = receiverAssembly,
                ReceiverClass = receiverClass,
                ReceiverName = receiverName,
            };

        documentLibrary.EventReceivers.Add(eventReceiver);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

But it seems that this is for SP2013.

- When I used the SharePoint.Client.Runtime and SharePoint.Client dll
  of version 14.0.0.0, then it shows that **`EventReceiverType`** does
  not exists
- When I used the SharePoint.Client.Runtime and SharePoint.Client dll
  of version 15.0.0.0, then it gave me error

> Field or property "EventReceivers" does not exist

My question is : How we can attach the event receiver to the List/Library using CSOM C# for SP2010?

I have already gone through many posts on [SE](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) but some does not have solutions and some are for SP2013

Comment: Whats the basic reason behind adding event receiver via CSOM?

Comment: I am not having SharePoint Environment. I have just client machine so I am using C# CSOM (Not Powershell too)